# .inferHtmlResources() and resource

Tags: scala, gatling

I am trying out Gatling first time.

But when I try to add .inferHtmlResources() i got following error:

```
value inferHtmlResources is not a member of com.excilys.ebi.gatling.http.config.HttpProtocolConfigurationBuilder
```

The same mattes when I get to execute part for resources:

```
value resources is not a member of com.excilys.ebi.gatling.http.request.builder.PostHttpRequestBuilder
```

Pseodo part of what I am doing

Part 1:

```
val httpConf = httpConfig.baseURL(urlBase).inferHtmlResources()
```

Part 2:

```
    .exec(
      http("Login")
      .post(loginUrl+"/security/signin")
      .headers(actionPostHeaders)
      .param("""username""", """${loginName}""")
      .param("""key""", """${key}""")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(headerRegex("Location", """.*/loggedIn"""))
      .resources(http("request_5")
        .get(tipUrl + "/authentication/authenticated")
      )
    ).exitHereIfFailed

...
setUp(scn.users(numUsers).ramp(rampUp(numUsers)).protocolConfig(httpConf))
```

I am not used to Scala. But can it be the version of gatling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatling HTTP protocol settings are created using `http` method, fe.: `http.baseURL("http://localhost").inferHtmlResources()`. Moreover I see that you are using some `com.excilys.ebi.gatling` classes, I think that those are extremely old packages from times when Gatling was just an internal project. Please make sure you are using newest version of gatling from `io.gatling` package.

Comment: Thank for response. The project is using 1.5.3 I guess that answer is to use version >2